# How to remove sections of lcov-report completely using nyc?

Tags: code-coverage, cypress, lcov, nyc

*I'm using the @cypress/code-coverage plugin.

I have tried to include only the directory I want:

```
{
    "extends": "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript",
    "all": true,
    "report-dir": "cypress-coverage",
    "reporter": ["text-summary", "lcov"],
    "include": ["src/**/*.js"]
}
```

But these other directories (which are siblings to `src/`), although they are showing 0/0 lines and 0% - keep showing on the report:
[image]

Also, I'm guessing they're not being included in the calculations since they are 0/0's, but is there some documentation out there that I can reference?  Seems hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

This got it working for me after I realized everything was a directory up:

```
{
    "extends": "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript",
    "all": true,
    "report-dir": "cypress-coverage",
    "reporter": ["text-summary", "lcov"],
    "include": ["**/src"],
    "exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```